# Proof of a theorem in distribution theory (probably Cochran's Theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence, chi-squared

I want to prove the following theorem (I'm not sure but probably it is called Cochran's Theorem) :

**Let $X$ follows $n$-variate multivariate normal distribution with mean vector $\mathbf{\mu}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Also let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_m$ be symmetric projection matrices of order $n$ such that $rank(A_i)=r_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m A_i=I$. Let $U_i=X^TA_iX$. Show that $U_i$'s are independent random variables, respectively distributed as $\chi_{r_i}^2$.**

I cannot find the idea to attack the problem. If anyone can give me any lead (even for the simple $m=2$ case, which I may generalize), I'll me much grateful. Thank you.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem

Comment: I saw the proof in Wiki. But I was wondering if one can give ideas on a simpler proof.